# How to unzip/extract files using phonegap for ios?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I have an app in which i want to download a zip file and extract the files to a specific folder. I managed to download a zip file but have issues in extracting it as I'm not able to find any good plugin for the same.
Any suggestions on how to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

use this plugin https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-zip

be careful where you save the files example:

```
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library"/>
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility"/>
```